# This may be another well known riddle, but maybe not

Tags: riddle

A man is discovered dead in the snow next to a rock, he is well known, but nobody can figure out how he died. There are no footprints leading to or away from the rock, and because none of the other townspeople drop dead as a result of their proximity with the rock, they decide that it is harmless. Who is the dead man? How did he die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really old one

The man is

> Superman

He died because

> the rock is Kryptonite

Comment: Very good, this is the right answer.

Comment: @Walker: I didn't think kryptonite killed Superman - I thought it only weakened him.

Comment: well maybe it weakened him enough so that the fall killed him, and prolonged exposure definitely would kill him.

Answer (score 2):

He's

> a skydiver who forgot his parachute.

Alternatively:

> it snowed after the man died and he's just *really* allergic to rocks.

Comment: The snow was there before the man died, and he was not a skydiver, or allergic to rocks.

Comment: @Walker The second one was a joke. :P

Comment: I've heard some pretty ridiculous answers to riddles and jokes, usually titled un-jokes. For instance, "What's big, red, and eats rocks?"

Comment: Answer, "A big red rock eater."

Answer (score 1):

This will be a bit push, but i'll try anyway
He

> is a miner and died of an heart attack, because he was searching minerals and this rock was the beginning of a diamond vessel, therefore he got pretty excited. No footprints, because he had worn skis

Comment: Good thinking, but no.